# Need to bypass this validation Rule which is causing while creating the b2b records, for the live chat, Can any one please help me how should i bypass

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

> FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, must populate atleast contact : téléphone / e-mail.: []
> Class.LiveChatTranscriptUtils.createPersonAccount: line 307, column 1
> Class.LiveChatTranscriptHandler.afterUpdate: line 95, column 1
> Trigger.LiveChatTranscriptTrigger: line 39, column

```java
/*********************************************************************************************************
   
    * @description     :   Update Live Chat Transcript Owner 
    * @param           chatTranscriptNew LiveChatTranscript
    * @param           chatTranscriptOld LiveChatTranscript 
    * @Returns         :   void
**********************************************************************************************************/
    Public static void updateLiveChatTransciptOwner(LiveChatTranscript chatTranscriptNew, LiveChatTranscript chatTranscriptOld){      
        
        String currentUser = userinfo.getusername();
        system.debug('currentUser==>'+currentUser);
        system.debug('chatTranscriptNew.ownerId==>'+chatTranscriptNew.ownerId);
        system.debug('chatTranscriptOld.ownerId==>'+chatTranscriptOld.ownerId);
        if(currentUser.startsWith('autoproc')){
            if(chatTranscriptNew.ownerId != null && chatTranscriptOld.ownerId != null && (String.valueOf(chatTranscriptNew.ownerId) != String.valueOf(chatTranscriptOld.ownerId)) && (UserInfo.getUserId() == chatTranscriptNew.ownerId)){
             chatTranscriptNew.ownerId = chatTranscriptOld.ownerId;
            }
        } 
        if (chatTranscriptNew.Status == 'Completed' && chatTranscriptOld.Status != 'Completed') {   
            if(((String)chatTranscriptNew.ownerId).startsWith('005')){  
                chatTranscriptNew.IsTreatedByAgent__c = true;   
            }else if (((String)chatTranscriptNew.ownerId).startsWith('00G')) {  
                chatTranscriptNew.IsTreatedByAgent__c = false;  
            }   
        }
    }
        
    /*********************************************************************************************************
    * @Method          :   createPersonAccount
  
    * @description     :   Create Person Account For Contact.
    * @param           chatTranscriptList List<LiveChatTranscript> , List<Id> transcriptContactIds
    * @param           transcriptContactIds List<Id> 
    * @Returns         :   void
    **********************************************************************************************************/   
    public static void createPersonAccount(List<LiveChatTranscript> chatTranscriptList, List<Id> transcriptContactIds){
        List<LiveChatTranscript> transcriptsToUpdate     = new List<LiveChatTranscript>();
        List<Account>            newB2BAccounts       = new List<Account>();
        Map<Id, Contact>         transcriptContactDetails;
        List<Id> accLst = new List<Id>();
        Map<String,Id> mapAccCon = new Map<String,Id>();
        Map<Id,Id> mapAccConId = new Map<Id,Id>();
        List<Account> updateB2CAcc = new List<Account>();
        List<Id> listIdLiveChatTranscript = new List<Id>();
        
        for(LiveChatTranscript chatTranscript : chatTranscriptList){
            listIdLiveChatTranscript.add(chatTranscript.Id);
        }
    
        Map<Id,LiveChatTranscript> mapLiveChatTranscript = new Map<Id,LiveChatTranscript>(
            [SELECT Id, owner.name, Case.ContactId, Case.Chat_Button_Queue_Name__c, LiveChatButtonId, LiveChatButton.MasterLabel, LiveChatButton.Queue.Name ,LiveChatButton.DeveloperName
             FROM LiveChatTranscript where Id IN :listIdLiveChatTranscript]);
        system.debug('mapLiveChatTranscript==>'+mapLiveChatTranscript);
        //Get the correct record type id for B2B
        Id b2bRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Account_B2B').getRecordTypeId();

        //Retrieve additional needed attributes on the chat transcript
        transcriptContactDetails = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT FirstName
                                                         , LastName
                                                         , Email
                                                         , AccountId
                                                         FROM Contact WHERE Id IN: transcriptContactIds]);

   
        for (LiveChatTranscript transcript : chatTranscriptList) {
            system.debug('userinfo.getusername==='+ UserInfo.getUserName());
        
            if (transcript.ContactId != null && transcriptContactDetails.containsKey(transcript.ContactId) && transcriptContactDetails.get(transcript.ContactId).AccountId == null && mapLiveChatTranscript.size() > 0 && (mapLiveChatTranscript.get(transcript.Id).LiveChatButton.DeveloperName.split('_')[3] == 'UK' || mapLiveChatTranscript.get(transcript.Id).LiveChatButton.DeveloperName.split('_')[3] == 'ES')) {
                String transcriptname = transcript.Name;
                transcriptsToUpdate.add(transcript);
                newB2BAccounts.add(new Account(RecordTypeId = b2bRecordType,
                                                   Name   = transcript.Name,
                                               OwnerId= '0050O000007Y6XUQA0' //Owner of AccountRecord to be "Automated Process" same as ContactRecord
                                               
                                          ));
                mapAccCon.put(transcriptname,transcript.ContactId);                       
            }
        }
    
        if(newB2BAccounts.size()>0){
            insert newB2BAccounts;
        
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,'Entering Accounts'+newB2BAccounts);
            
            for(Account a: newB2BAccounts){
                Id contactId;
                accLst.add(a.id);
                contactId = mapAccCon.get(a.Name);
                mapAccConId.put(contactId,a.Id);
                
            }
        }
    
        //Update Contact With Account and change Record Type To B2C Personal Account
        if(mapAccConId.size() > 0){
            for(Contact con : transcriptContactDetails.values()){
                con.AccountId= mapAccConId.get(con.Id);
            } 
            update transcriptContactDetails.values();
            
           List<LiveChatTranscript> lstTranscriptToUpdate = new List<LiveChatTranscript>();
            for (LiveChatTranscript transcript : chatTranscriptList) {  
                lstTranscriptToUpdate.add(new LiveChatTranscript(Id = transcript.id,
                AccountId= mapAccConId.get(transcript.ContactId)));
                
            }
            
            if(!lstTranscriptToUpdate.isEmpty()){
           // update lstTranscriptToUpdate;
            }

           
           //String b2cRecordTypePersonal = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('B2C_Local').getRecordTypeId(); 
             
            String b2cRecordTypePersonal = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('B2C_PA').getRecordTypeId(); 
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,'Entering Accounts RecordType'+b2cRecordTypePersonal);
            for(Account upAcc : newB2BAccounts) {
                updateB2CAcc.add(new Account(Id = upAcc.Id,RecordTypeId = b2cRecordTypePersonal ));
            }
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,'Entering Accounts updateB2CAcc '+updateB2CAcc);
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,'Entering Accounts Update ');
            if(updateB2CAcc.size() > 0){
                update updateB2CAcc; 
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,'Entering Accounts update updateB2CAcc  '+updateB2CAcc);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Line no 307: insert newB2BAccounts;

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new boolean field on the object you want to bypass
  validation.
- Call it something like VR_Override__c.
- Set it to `true` when inserting the object.
- In the validation rule, add an `AND(VR_Override__c = FALSE, "current conditions"`
- Whenever you populate the phone or email, also set the VS_Override__c to `false`

It's not the cleanest solution but I've used it before without issues.